# How to pass HTML form input to Python script?

Tags: python, html

I have form tags like this

```
<form name="input_form" action="/test.py" method="get">
    Set Frequency: <input type="number" name="set_freq" id="set_freq"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" /><br>
</form>
```

I need to have it where, the user enter 1500 or whatever value, and then once submit is hit, that number is passed to the python program, test.py for right now.

Comment: Have you tried implementing flask? Flask will make this a whole lot easier....

Comment: I would argue Flask makes everything worse and harder than it need-be! There are arguably much better webservers like [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/)

Comment: I tried flask and yeah it seemed like it just cause a lot of problems. I've tried using cgi but didn't get anywhere with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that, you can use CGI (a webserver that calls your python script and serves the output) or a WSGI framework like Django or Flask, or others. Of course, these also need to be served, either from a "typical" webserver like apache or Nginx or something like Gunicorn.

my recommendation is to use a framework like Flask to accomplish that task.

install it by running, preferably in a virtual env:

```
pip install flask
```

then you could write something simple as

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template 
  
# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)   
  
# A decorator used to tell the application
# which URL is associated function
@app.route('/test.py', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def get_freq():
    if request.method == "POST":
       # getting input with freq = set_freq in HTML form
       freq = request.form.get("set_freq") # <--- do whatever you want with that value
       return "Your freq value is " + freq
    return render_template("form.html")
  
if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run()
```

then you will need to provide your `form.html` template to be served, and put it in the `./templates` folder.

```html
<form action="{{ url_for("get_freq") }}" method="post">
<label for="set_freq">Set Frequency:</label>
<input type="number" id="set_freq" name="set_freq" >
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

now run the script and open http://127.0.0.1:5000/test.py
you will be served with the form and by submitting it you will send the freq value straight to the backend where you can interpret it.

**for learning purposes:**

for learning purposes, you can use the HTTP server in the python standard library without using a framework. this not intended for production and even could take more effort than using web frameworks (this is the point of using such frameworks).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Usage::
    ./server.py [<port>]
"""
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self, code):
        self.send_response(code)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.info("GET request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n", str(self.path), str(self.headers))
        query_components = parse_qs(urlparse(self.path).query)
        if query_components.get('set_freq'):
            freq = query_components.get('set_freq') # <--- do whatever you want with that value
            print(freq)
        self._set_response(200)
        self.wfile.write("Python HTTP server received your GET request".encode("utf-8"))
        

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8080):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    logging.info('Starting httpd...\n')
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    logging.info('Stopping httpd...\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

run the web server and as it starts to listen to incoming requests you can now open your form page and submit your data. you'll need to edit the path where your form will send the data, here is the final snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form name="input_form" action="http://localhost:8080">
    Set Frequency: <input type="number" name="set_freq" id="set_freq"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" /><br>
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form data will be sent to your local Python 3 HTTP server.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

again this is nowhere a complete or optimized or production code.
use it just in case you want to get something up and running to play with and learn.

**code Explanation:**

`BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class is used to handle the HTTP requests that arrive at the server. By itself, it cannot respond to any actual HTTP requests; it must be subclassed to handle each request method (e.g. GET or POST). so we extend it in `S` class by adding the `do_GET` method that will be called on GET requests.

from Python official doc:

> The handler will parse the request and the headers, then call a method
> specific to the request type. The method name is constructed from the
> request. For example, for the request method SPAM, the do_SPAM()
> method will be called with no arguments. All of the relevant
> information is stored in instance variables of the handler. Subclasses
> should not need to override or extend the **init**() method.

read more from here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.HTTPServer

Comment: Thank for your answer, I appreciate it. So when I make that run and the set_freq variable is populated, then how do I get to it from there? I have an API to use, would I add this in that API? Or would this be a separate standing program?

Comment: @luke you run the script and it should be kept running in the background, then when you submit the form, the script will get your value in the line where I commented it by `do whatever you want with that value `. this line simply print the value put you could do anything else. please check the code. also, I updated my answer to refer to Flask tutorial to use when you decide to go with the recommended way,

Comment: also, you could share more about the actual code you use in test.py so I can help you further or If you have any queries please don't hesitate to comment below.

Comment: Thank you so much, super great explanation, you're the best. I appreciate it!

Comment: @luke glad I helped. I updated the answer again for the sake of completeness. in the meantime, if this answer satisfies your needs please mark it as an accepted answer.